# How to disable media query page break (small grid) on Foundation 4 after re sizing browser?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I got a small page where I must use Foundation 4. The problem is that I use the RoyalSlider plugin for the gallery. If I'm on a big screen it works quite well. It looks like this:

http://jan-schloesser.noip.me/phpfundamentals/gallery/example-slideshow.php

But if you're resizing the browser window to a minimum, the grid set the width of the photos automatically to 100%. How can I disable the small grid in Foundation 4?

Here is the code segment:

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    <img src="link_to_image" alt="">
    <img src="link_to_image" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For best results, please update your question with the relevant code snippets. For more information, please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thanks for the welcome greetings. Yip, that's true, but this is a generally question about Foundation 4.

Comment: The link doesn't load, but if you just don't want the images to be 100% at a certain size, then set the css for the royalSlider in a media query where appropriate (a max-width so it doesn't screw up larger viewports) : .royalSlider img {max-width:none;width:auto;}